# Is $[(x_{1}^2 x_{2}^2+x_{3}^2)^2+ x_{4}^2]^{-1/2}$ locally integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let
\begin{equation}
f(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x_{1}^2 x_{2}^2+x_{3}^2)^2+ x_{4}^2}} \quad (x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \backslash \{0 \}).
\end{equation}
Is $f$ locally integrable?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: why shouldn't it

Comment: Please involve some thoughts yourself. When you have come to the level of dealing with locally integrability, I think you could at least show some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ops, this is a really trivial exercise. I don't know why I could not see that this function is locally integrable at first glance. Maybe I am too tired in the last days. Anyhow, we have
\begin{equation}
f(x) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_{3}^4 + x_{4}^2}},
\end{equation}
and we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_{3}^4 + x_{4}^2}} dx_3 dx_4 =
\int_{-1}^{1}  \log \left( \frac{\sqrt{1+x_{3}^4}+1}{\sqrt{1+x_{3}^4}-1} \right) dx_3 = \int_{-1}^{1}  2 \log \left( \frac{\sqrt{1+x_{3}^4}+1}{x_{3}^2} \right) dx_3
\end{equation}
which is clearly integrable since 
\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^{1} - \log(x^2)dx = -4 \int_{0}^{1}  \log(x)dx = 4.
\end{equation}
Sorry for having posted it!